# COM dll called from PHP doesn't empty variables

Tags: iis, dll, com, vb6

the problem I'm having started to appear lately and it doesn't appear everywhere.

The front end (html/js) calls PHP pages. PHP in turn calls functions from a COM dll (vb6). The COM dll does use some lower level C++ .dlls in turns, though not sure this information is relevant.

Now, lately (this did not happen before), in one specific COM dll function, let's call it `BringClients()`, sometimes (apparently some user concurrency happening - race condition?) a global variable let's say `ClientName` which is used within `BringClients()` is not empty when the function is called, but instead it holds a value, which is set on function `UpdateClients()` when this function is called in a completely different instance of the COM dll, by a completely different user.

I don't know why this is happening. Aren't all COM dll variables empty when the .dll is initialized? I worked around it by manually emptying the variable on each initilization of the .dll, but should this even be happening? I haven't noticed a similar issue on other functions.

The OS is Windows server with IIS.

Comment: Shared/global variables are usual suspects in such cases.

Comment: That or someone didn't know that VB6 (as most BASICs) defaults to passing variables `ByRef` instead of `ByVal` and `ClientName` gets passed to `UpdateClients()`, is altered there _(and therefore its also altered in the calling code)_ and subsequently passed to `BringClients()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how PHP interacts with COM components, but my guess is you don't really initialize the DLL, you create objects. And your COM library is apartment-threaded, so you will get an isolated set of variables per thread.

But what happens if IIS uses the same thread later (from a pool) based upon whatever scheduling it uses to balance requests? Then any global/public module-level data variables will still be there.

So yes, if you need to ensure that those variables are not re-used you are going to have to clear them or re-architect to remove all globals.